# Total number of users differs in the "Reports" and the "Explorer" tabs in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am using GA4.

Over the same date range, the total number of active users is **15% greater** when I look at the demographic data in the "Reports" tab, when compared to the number of users in the "Explorer" tab.

"Reports" tab : (sorry, it's in French)
[image]

"Explorer" tab :
[image]

I confirm that there are no filters in my custom report in the "Explorer" tab.

Which number is correct?
If the correct number id the one from the "Reports" tab, how can I obtain the same number in the "Explorer" tab?

Comment: Please attach screenshots of both.

Comment: Now it's done. Sorry it's in French...

Comment: Also, I wanted to add that my number of custom events is consistent between both tabs. It's just the number of users which isn't.

Comment: I looked again at my "Report" tab this morning and the total number of users has changed ! It is now at 10955 ! I don't understand.

Comment: However, the number of new users and returning users is now the same in both tabs.

Comment: Is it possible that it took 1 week to Google Analytics' "Report" tab to process the data?

Comment: no, GA's official claim is that it takes up to two days for free accounts, so a week is extremely unlikely. That stuff can happen when you've selected a user dimension in one report that was unset for N users and then became set, but that's not the case I recon.